# New domain for ftp

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

Basically i have an FTP server on a server in the domain mydomain.com. I set up an entry in DNS to access this ftp server via ftp.mydomain.com. However his appears to have been taken hence i cannot access it outside of the network.

My question is, how to i add an entry so i can access the ftp server via ftp.domain2.com. Where domain2 is of course different from mydomain?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are controlling mydomain.com, how can it be taken?

Comment: because if i try to access ftp.mydomain.com from other computers on my network it does not work, however it does work if i just use the machine name. Have I completely got this wrong or something???

Answer (score 2):

Just setup a DNS record to point at the FTP server IP.  FTP really don't care much about names.

Comment: How? If I do that through the DNS manager it automatically includes the Fully qualified domain name. Forgive me but I am very new to all this!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, my question is, how do i add a record into dns for ftp.domain2.com?

Comment: Do you already own domain2.com?  If not, buy that domain, set it up on your DNS server, and add a record named 'ftp'.

Comment: No domain2.com does not exist. Sorry for confusion. Basically it boils down to this, how do i add an entry for ftp.domain2.com on an ftp server which is part of mydomain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to you internal DNS server? If so, it is likely not externally accessible or authoritative as far as the greater Internet is concerned.

Confirm that first and if it's true, find out who is hosting your DNS in the real world and make updates there.

Comment: No this is my internal dns server. Let me try and make myself more clear: I added an entry for ftp.mydomain.com into the dns server. With this i can access the ftp on my actual server, but not from other computers on my network. This is due to the fact that ftp.mydomain.com is already taken.

Comment: double check your dns settings on your client machines. ipconfig /all and then try nslookup ftp.mydomain.com from the client. This will return the server it is trying to resolve against with the result.

Comment: I did the ns lookup, and it seems like it is trying to find it on by router. Also, the client computers do not know about the dns server, does this mean that it does not know about the entry for ftp.domain2.com.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an internal DNS server, the DNS entry will only work on computers that are on that same network, have the DNS server accessible to them, AND are configured to use that DNS server for name resolution.  Computers outside of your network will not be able to access those DNS records and the entry will not work for them.

If the actual "real" DNS records for your .com are being managed elsewhere, for example with a domain registrar, you need to make that change there.  That will populate the DNS change through authoritative sources.  This is assuming that the FTP server IP you are assigning to ftp.mydomain.com is a public IP and not a private internal IP, or that you are pointing ftp.mydomain.com to a router on a public IP that is handing traffic off to your DNS server...

You can force entries for other domains in a DNS server, but all of the client computers again have to be going to YOUR DNS server as their authoritative source.   You can also edit the hosts file manually on each computer to accomplish the same...